# Failed to crunch file - Gradle tasks failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new using android studio and programming on android and I'm getting this error:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
>
> Error:Failed to crunch file
>   C:\Users\alexa\Documents\Projectos\Blueprint Apocalypse\Mobile
>   Application\Blueprint_App\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png
>   into C:\Users\alexa\Documents\Projectos\Blueprint Apocalypse\Mobile
>   Application\Blueprint_App\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\alexa\Documents\Projectos\Blueprint Apocalypse\Mobile Application\Blueprint_App\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png into C:\Users\alexa\Documents\Projectos\Blueprint Apocalypse\Mobile Application\Blueprint_App\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the problem here is with the **path of the project**.

***Please move it to short path***, like - C:\Users\alexa\Documents\YourProject.

I had this problem before and it worked after moving project location to a short path.

Weird but only workaround I know.

Answer (score 0):

Clean project.

```
Build > Clean Project
```

Another option is goto build.gradle in project section and downgrading the gradle version

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'
}
```